# how to perform backspace and delete?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm developing a code in where I need to perform a delete and backspace from `UITextView`. 
I tried:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    uitextview.text =[uitextview.text substringToIndex:[uitextview.text length]-1];
}
```

this perform back space and remove last character but how to delete a character from specific location in `uitextview` on a particular cursor location.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for ur suggest.I want to suggest one way to perform this work.

```
 NSRange range = uitextview.selectedRange;


    NSRange selectedRange = uitextview.selectedRange;

    NSLog(@"%d",selectedRange.length);
    NSLog(@"%d",selectedRange.location);
    int temploc=selectedRange.location;

    NSMutableString *text = [uitextview.text mutableCopy];
    // NSLog(@"Length: %d Location: %d", range.length, range.location);
    if (range.length > 0) {
        [text deleteCharactersInRange:range];
    }
    if (range.length == 0 && range.location != 0) {
        NSRange backward = NSMakeRange(range.location - 1, 1);
        // NSLog(@"Length: %d Location: %d", backward.length, backward.location);
        [text deleteCharactersInRange:backward];
    }

    uitextview.text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selectedRange` property of the `UITextView`. This indicates the cursor position and/or selected text (the length will be zero if no text is selected).

So, if the range.length is > 0, you can use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` to delete the selected text.

Otherwise, create a new range with location one less than your selected range and length of 1, and then remove this character.

You may need to re-set the `selectedRange` property to make sure the cursor ends up in the appropriate position. I imagine all this is done automatically when using the standard keyboard.

Comment: i HAve tried to use NSRange selectedRange = uitextview.selectedRange;
 
 NSLog(@"%d",selectedRange.length);
 NSLog(@"%d",selectedRange.location);
 int temploc=selectedRange.location;
and in the remove location i give the temp location but it dosn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, does my updated answer help? If not, can you update the question with the code you are using and the results you are getting ("doesn't work" isn't very helpful)